# summing column excel vba multiple external files iteration

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, sum

I have a VBA code that I use for refreshing all the Excel data files (worksheet *Analysis* in each file) in a specified folder (refreshing is done via XL3 add-in in Excel). It works perfectly.

```
Sub refresh_OGSC_data_files()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook

Set FileSystemObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FolderObj = FileSystemObj.GetFolder("C:\ARBEIT\Projects\ONEGSC impact     simulation\Part 2\Data\EE")

For Each fileobj In FolderObj.Files
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileobj.Path)

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AUX").Range("B2") = "12"
    Application.Run "XL3RefreshGrid", "Analysis!A13"

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next fileobj

End Sub
```

**What I'm trying to add into it, is a funcionality, which would sum column M in each of these files and "record" this value into a cell in external workbook -  e.g. Book1, Sheet1, Cell A1.** (For second refreshed file it would be cell A2. for third file cell A3, and so on, until the last file)

I was trying to insert this into the same code (before saving the refreshed file: *ActiveWorkbook.Save*):

```
Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Workbooks("wb").Worksheets("Analysis").Range("m:m"))
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

However it doesn't work and is probably completely wrong. Please help.

If anything is unclear I will try to elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you show use your `wB` reference to the opened workbook :

```
Sub refresh_OGSC_data_files()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wB As Workbook
    Dim SumResult As Double
    Dim OutPutRange As Range

    Set FileSystemObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set FolderObj = FileSystemObj.GetFolder("C:\ARBEIT\Projects\ONEGSC impact     simulation\Part 2\Data\EE")
    Set OutPutRange = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")

    For Each fileobj In FolderObj.Files

        Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fileobj.Path)

        wB.Sheets("AUX").Range("B2") = "12"
        Application.Run "XL3RefreshGrid", "Analysis!A13"

        SumResult = WorksheetFunction.Sum(wB.Sheets("Analysis").Range("M:M"))
        OutPutRange.Value = SumResult
        Set OutPutRange = OutPutRange.Offset(1, 0)
        TotalSum = TotalSum + SumResult

        wB.Save
        wB.Close
    Next fileobj

    Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = TotalSum
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the code below to the Loop where you are calculating the Sum from Column M (you need to raise `i` by 1 to raise the row index by 1).

The code below is without `Activate`, `Select` and `ActiveCell`, but uses qualified `Range`s and `Worksheets`.

**Code**

```
Dim SumSht  As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set SumSht = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
i = 1

' loop here every time to raise the row index (of i)
SumSht.Range("A" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(wb.Worksheets("Analysis").Range("M:M"))
i = i + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @shai. Not yet working though. It gets stuck on this line: `SumSht.Range("A" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Workbooks("wb").Worksheets("Analysis").Range("M:M"))`  I guess that the _wb_ is not implemented correctly. WorksheetFunction.Sum worked fine without _Workbooks("wb")_

Comment: Works as well. Thank you!

Comment: @andhisbrother  why did u remove the answer ? You can also upvote u know ?

Comment: I can only mark one answer as the one that solved the problem. and the R3uK was faster with the final solution by a minute maybe. I've upvoted now so maybe you get some points, but it won't show publicly, because I don't have enough points they say.